# Importance of graph planarity for applications

Tags: graph-theory, applications, planar-graphs

What is the real-life motivation for studying (or inventing) effective algorithms to check whether or not a graph is planar (which seems to have garnered interest in recent years)? Why is planarity an important property of a graph from the "applications" point of view? The single application that I know is related to the design of 2D circuits, e.g. minimizing the number of intersections of wires.

Comment: @Marios Gretsas What was your motivation in rejecting this-> https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/857354 suggested edit? I can't correct grammar mistakes if the corrections are rejected straight away!

Comment: @John Griffin same question

Comment: Planarity of graphs figured prominently in [my Answer to a Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458172/3111) about mathematical games.  Do games count as applications?

Comment: It might be a bit tangential, but I responded to [this previous Question about good planarity tests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444332/what-is-a-good-planar-graph-test) with some historical exposition.  It might be interesting to you.